# Display all results when a checkbox is unchecked with angularjs filters

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, filter

I'm just trying to do a simple thing which give me headache.

In an app with Angularjs, I have a dictionary with values. I want to filter my values using a checkbox.
If the checkbox is checked, the list is refreshed with the elements which have is_streaming : TRUE.
But if the checkbox is unchecked. I want to show all the results.

For the moment, when the checkbox is checked, it shows only the good events (it's exactly what I want) but when I uncheck, I have only the elements with FALSE.

```
var events = [{
    id: 0,
    event_name: 'Concert 1',
    is_streaming: 'true'
  }, {
    id: 1,
    event_name: 'Concert 2',
    is_streaming: 'true'
  },{
    id: 2,
    event_name: 'Concert 3',
    is_streaming: 'true'
  }



<ion-toggle ng-model="is_streaming" toggle-class="toggle-calm">En ce moment</ion-toggle>
<ion-list>
 <ion-item class="" ng-repeat="event in filtered=(events | filter:is_streaming)" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/chats//{{event.id}}">
  <div class="player" ng-show="{{event.is_streaming}} == true"></div>
 </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Any help or advices will be good to hear. THX

Comment: Can you put a fiddle/plunker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Change your checkbox attributes to use the ng-false-value and set it to null:

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="search.is_streaming" ng-false-value="null" toggle-class="toggle-calm">En ce moment</ion-toggle>
```

Then you can use:

```
<ion-item class="" ng-repeat="event in events | filter: search.is-streaming" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/chats//{{event.id}}">
```

Comment: I tried your example but the console gave me an error 'code'Error: [ngModel:constexpr] Expected constant expression for `ngFalseValue`, but saw ``.'code'

Comment: Interesting.  Worked perfectly for me.  Will have to test in an ionic project.  I tested with a checkbox in Plunker before posting.

Comment: Sorry, you were correct and it threw an error for me too with latest build.  It was an easy fix though by just setting the ng-false-value to null.

Comment: Works perfectly with ng-false-value="null" ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

So if you only want to check the value of is_streaming you don't need to use filter, it's better to use ngIf to do this, look the following [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPMvvo) :

I switched one value to false to test it.
ng-if syntax :

```
    <span ng-if"expression">display what you need </span>
```